# Cypress get index row that contain the element I have with the given data attribute

Tags: indexing, get, row, cypress

I have a mat-table with

```
  <mat-row>
        <mat-cell>Firstname</mat-cell>
        <mat-cell>Lastname</mat-cell> 
        <mat-cell>Age</mat-cell>
      </mat-row>
      <mat-row>
        <mat-cell>Jill</mat-cell>
        <mat-cell>Smith</mat-cell> 
        <mat-cell> <mat-icon data-mat-icon-name="pinned"> </mat-cell>
      </mat-row>
```

And I need to know the row index of the element that has `data-mat-icon-name='pinned'`

I tried the below code:

```
   cy.get("mat-table").find("[data-mat-icon-name='pinned']").invoke("index").then((i) => {
      cy.log(i); // prints 0. Should print 1
    });
```

But gives me index 0. Should give index 1.

So maybe is just giving some index of the cell and not of the row?

Any idea how I can get the row index?

Do. I need to use cy.parent ?

**Edit:**

If I do `cy.get("mat-table").find("[data-mat-icon-name='pinned']").should("exist");`

The element exits in the Dom

Comment: What about if you use `mat-row` instead of `mat-table` as your locator ?

Comment: @AlapanDas. I don't know the row ... I want to find the element and then find the row that contain the element

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the jQuery docs [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object **relative to its sibling elements**.

But the `<mat-icon>` you find is by itself in the cell.

You need to navigate to the parent row and find it's index among siblings,

```js
cy.get('mat-table')
  .find('[data-mat-icon-name=pinned]')
  .parents('mat-row')
  .invoke('index')
  .then((i) => {
    cy.log(i); // prints 1
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Turns out it was such a simple problem.